# Configuring address and ports for JGroups

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

When using JGroups, with a component such as Infinispan, it is possible to configure the ports and addresses that JGroups will use.

```
http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/user-advanced.html
```

For example:

```
<UDP
        mcast_addr="${jgroups.udp.mcast_addr:228.6.7.8}"
        mcast_port="${jgroups.udp.mcast_port:46655}"
        ...
```

But here is what is confusing me.  How can all members of the cluster all use the same port, addr?

I would have thought each member would have its own port and have to know the ports (and addresses) of the other members it needs to talk to?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multicast is a special address that can be used by multiple nodes to send/received data - think of it like 127.0.0.1, which is also available on most boxes with network installed.